Can we show that the following integral is independent of $\phi_0$ without computing the integral itself?
$$\int_0^{2\pi N} d\phi \sin^4\left(\dfrac{\phi}{2N}\right)\sin^2\left(\phi+\phi_0\right)$$
Here $N$ is an integer greater than $1$ and $\phi_0$ is a constant phase.
Context: while studying laser pulses I have read upon a typical choice of a function to represent them:
$$\psi\left(\phi\right)=\sin^2\left(\dfrac{\phi}{2N}\right)\sin(\phi+\phi_0).$$ The energy of the pulse is proportional to the integral of the square of this function over a whole period of the laser pulse, in this case its $2\pi N$. I have already computed this integral and have seen its independent of $\phi_0$ whenever $N$ is an integer. However, I think the fact that its independent of $\phi_0$ is more general than the specific integrand we are dealing with here. Probably it has something to do with the period of $\sin^4\left(\dfrac{\phi}{2N}\right)$ being $2N$ times the period of $\sin^2\left(\phi+\phi_0\right).$ Is there a way to show this algebraically.

@TedShifrin differentiating it does not help as you still get cosine term.

@TedShifrin  After differentiating, if its $\sin(2(\phi-\phi_0))$ you are referring to, it is not an odd function with respect to $\phi$.

Not very elegant: by using power reduction formulae and product to sum formulae, the integrating function can be written
\begin{align}
\sin^4\left(\dfrac{\phi}{2N}\right)\sin^2\left(\phi+\phi_0\right) 
  &= \frac{1}{32} \bigg[
    -8\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{N}\right) 
    +2\cos\left(\frac{2 \phi}{N}\right) \\
  & +4\cos\left(\frac{2N-1}{N}\phi+2\phi_0\right) 
    +4\cos\left(\frac{2N+1}{N}\phi+2\phi_0\right) \\
  & -\cos\left(\frac{2N-2}{N}\phi+2\phi_0\right)
    -\cos\left(\frac{2N+2}{N}\phi+2\phi_0\right) \\
  & -6\cos\left(2\phi+2\phi_0\right) 
    +6
  \bigg]
\end{align}
and all terms, but the last, are periodic functions with mean value zero and integrated over a multiple of their period.
